# Split column into different fields with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I transform the source table to the target table?
for example, P111 and C111 are connected. I want them in the same row and whenever they are connected case_type should policy.

1.A claim/Policy combo share a ID and are prefixed with P for policy and C for claim.

2.The policy-date for a claim and policy are identical for a given ID.

3.There is a 1 to 1 relationship for policies and claims.

4.If there is a policy and a claim, the case_type should be policy.

```
Source Table                               Target Table
+-----------+-------------+-----------+    +--------+-------+-------------+-----------+
| policy_id | policy_date | case_type |    | Policy | Claim | policy_date | case_type |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+    +--------+-------+-------------+-----------+
| p111      | 2017-05-10  | Policy    |    | p103   | c103  | 2017-06-10  | Policy    |
| c111      | 2017-05-10  | Claim     |    | p111   | c111  | 2017-05-10  | Policy    |
| p103      | 2017-06-10  | Policy    |    | p124   | NULL  | 2017-05-10  | Policy    |
| c103      | 2017-06-10  | Claim     |    | NULL   | c133  | 2017-06-10  | Claim     |
| p124      | 2017-05-10  | Policy    |    | p144   | NULL  | 2017-09-10  | Policy    |
| c133      | 2017-06-10  | Claim     |    | p155   | c155  | 2017-07-10  | Policy    |
| p155      | 2017-06-10  | Policy    |    | NULL   | c177  | 2017-09-10  | Claim     |
| c155      | 2017-07-10  | Claim     |    |AI100   |EC100   |2017-08-10| Policy   +--------+-------+--------------+
| p144      | 2017-09-10  | Policy    |    
| c177      | 2017-09-10  | Claim     |  
| AI100     | 2017-08-10  | Policy    |
| EC100     | 2017-08-10  | Claim     |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: A self-join is the answer, so please post your attempt to do that, and what error you got.

Comment: How are you determining which Policy/Claim ID records get paired together?  I don't see anything that indicates one is related to the other.  What happened to `C155`?  Why are `P144` and `C177` on different lines?  What is your logic here...?

Comment: Is that PolicyDate of P155 a typo?

Comment: P155 was mistake it should be policydate on the left and c155 on the claim column right table.P144 and C177 are on separate lines because they have no policy or claim attached. the other ones are tied together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has a lot of assumptions as you did not provide any logic for how you want your first table to get to your second. Here are the assumptions I made:

1. A claim/Policy combo share a ID and are prefixed with P for policy and C for claim.
2. The policy-date for a claim and policy are identical for a given ID.
3. There is a 1 to 1 relationship for policies and claims.
4. If there is a policy and a claim, the case_type should be policy.

With these assumptions, here is the table variable I made to test this:

Edit: Updated for new sample data

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
policy_id NVARCHAR(5),
policy_date date,
case_type NVARCHAR(6)
)

INSERT @tbl VALUES
('p111','05/10/2017','Policy'), ('c111','05/10/2017','Claim'),
('p103','06/10/2017','Policy'), ('c103','06/10/2017','Claim'),
('p124','05/10/2017','Policy'), ('c133','06/10/2017','Claim'),
('p155','07/10/2017','Policy'), ('c155','07/10/2017','Claim'),
('p144','09/10/2017','Policy'), ('c177','09/10/2017','Claim'),
('AI100','2017-08-10','Policy'), ('EC100','2017-08-10','Claim')
```

And here is the query to get the result set you are looking for.

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE case_type
        WHEN 'Policy' THEN policy_id
        END) AS Policy,
    MAX(CASE case_type
        WHEN 'Claim' THEN policy_id
        END) AS Claim,
    MAX(policy_date) AS policy_date,
    MIN(CASE case_type          --This is a custom priority for which case_type is displayed.
        WHEN 'Policy' THEN 1    --If there is a policy then it's policy,
        WHEN 'Info Only' Then 2 --if there is no policy but there is an info only then it's info only,
        WHEN 'Claim' THEN 3     --and if it's only a claim then it's claim.
        END) AS case_type
FROM @tbl
GROUP BY
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(policy_id,'ai',''), 'ec', ''), 'c', ''), 'p', '')   --Does not include info only, I'm not sure what prefix is applied for that
    --SUBSTRING(policy_id, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', policy_id), 10)
```

The substring option is unnecessary for the current example set but is more thorough. It will strip any letters prefixing the numbers up to 10 digits (the limit for the int data type). See [this awesome blog](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/extracting-numbers-with-sql-server/) for more details, however as we are only stripping the letters prefixing it I stopped at step 2.

Comment: Your assumptions are right. I have no Claim column in the first table, I need to deduce it from the first table with a query.

Comment: It does not cause I  don't have claims column in the left table . both policy and claim are stored in policyID.

Comment: This query does not require a claims column in the left table, it creates it based on the policyID and case_type? Given the data you provided, this generates the output you asked for.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. It works . I also have cases where AP123 with  policy typeofcase and EC123 with Claims typeofcase. how do I handle it in the group by clause

Comment: To get the joining ID, replace AP or EC with nothing to get only the numbers. You will have to update the case statement as well if you want these to count as cases and claims.

Comment: REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(policy_id,'p',''), 'c', ''),'AI',''),'EC',''). I have tried this but not giving me desired result

Comment: The replace of c occurs before the replace of ec which is why the EC claim is not joining correctly. Either order it to replace the longest strings first (ai, ec, c, p) or leave it as it is and change the ec to e. The more possibilities there are, the more specific your replace logic will be. A more thorough but unnecessary method for the current example, would be to group by SUBSTRING(policy_id, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', policy_id), 8000). See [this awesome blog](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/extracting-numbers-with-sql-server/) for details. This only requires step 2.

Comment: Updated answer for new sample data.

Comment: Thanks very much, Andrew. I'm very grateful. I found out there's a third typeofcase (INFO Only )which shares ID with claims. Max or min(Typeofcase Case) doesn't seem to work. The Condition should be when 'info only' shares an ID with claim then 'Info only'. I couldn't write that conditions without having to include type of case in the Group by clause but this returns duplicates

Comment: I updated the answer with a custom priority for what is displayed as case_type. Please review this query and work to understand why it's doing what it's doing. Ideally you can adjust this for any additional changes you need without coming back to SO. Not that you shouldn't come back, but these updates are either not new functions, or were easily searchable.